# llvm: c interface getPointerToFunction equivalent

Tags: c, llvm

LLVM offers a function to access the adress of a JIT-compiled function, `getPointerToFunction` (see e.g. http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl4.html#adding-a-jit-compiler).

Since I prefer OCaml over C++ for the codegen part, I am pretty much limited to the C-interface of llvm (which in turn is the base for the OCaml interface).

When I look at the code at http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/OCamlLangImpl4.html, all I can see is `run_function`, which seems to recompile the function every time it is called. This leads to a 2000x slower code.

Is something like `getPointerToFunction` available to the C-interface or do I have to hack my way around somehow?

If it is not available, my idea would be to generate a second llvm function that yields the pointer to the compiled one. Is there a convenient way to do so, i.e. get the address of a llvm function via an instruction?